# How to process multiline parameters with PHP in linux command line

Tags: php

```
php test.php
```

I use the above command in the Linux shell environment. It prompts me to input the parameters. I want to input 3 lines of parameters but now it directly executes `test.php` when I hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: you need to add the command you're entering

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\n` to divide the lines and process the string inside the script to replace them with real line breaks.Example:

```
<?php
    echo str_replace('\n',"\n",$argv[1]);
?>
```